# Use COUNT * To Calculate Percentage In Same SELECT Statement

Tags: sql-server, select, while-loop, percentage

Suppose that I create T-SQL SELECT statement in a WHILE loop (say to iterate over year records).  I have a total count of records in the SELECT, and a count of a subset of records matching certain criteria.  Each loop iteration is added to a temp table as a new record.

Can I use a COUNT(*) total and a subtotal to calculate a percentage ***within the same SELECT***?  This would require the order of evaluation in the SELECT to be deterministic - that is, first appearing is first evaulated.  Example:

```
WHILE @yr < @CurrYr BEGIN
     INSERT INTO @tmpMatches(total_ct, match_ct, pct_match, yr
                             -- some other fields
                            )
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_ct,
            SUM(IIF(cd.is_matched = 1, 1, 0)) AS match_ct,
            ( CASE
                WHEN (total_ct > 0)
                    THEN (((@tmp_match_ct * 1.0) / 
                           (@tmp_total_ct * 1.0)) * 100)
                    ELSE 0
              END
            ) AS pct_match, 
            @yr
        FROM candidate cd
            INNER JOIN -- ...
        WHERE -- ...
           AND YEAR(closing_dt) = @yr
   SET @yr = @yr + 1;
-- ...
END -- while
```

If I couldn't rely on the evaluation order, it seems to me that I'd have to have a similar SELECT statement preceding this one, in order to get the overall total and subset before running the statement shown above.

In any case, is there a clearer, more SQL-like way to get this result?

Comment: I don't quite understand the code so the best I can offer is general advice: one of the [SQL Server Analytic functions dealing with percentages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) *may* be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one alternative that should work using two sub queries.

```
SELECT
    total_ct,
    match_ct,
    pct_match=CASE WHEN (total_ct>0) THEN ... ELSE 0 END
FROM
(
    SELECT
        total_ct=COUNT(*),
        match_ct=SUM(MatchedFlag)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            someid,
            MatchedFlag=CASE WHEN is_matched=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM
            candidate cd
    )AS Z   
)AS Y
```

Comment: I also think if you bring your year value up with and GROUP BY AVG Year at Z then you don't have to write a loop you can just insert the results of the query.